# Get SessionId in DNX / CoreCLR project

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, dnx

The whole `httpContext` has been changed in DNX.

I can read the full session with the `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session` (DNX 1.0.0-RC1-update1). The Session property is of type `ISession`:

[image: ISession interface]

But how do I read the sessionId?

Comment: I believe there's no such thing as dedicated session id of fixed type anymore. First of all, your app may not support sessions at all. And even if it does, session may be saved in whatever way your persistence engine likes. So if you need some kind of identifier assigned to your session, put it there and then use as any other stored value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session ids aren't supported anymore, found at [a related Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/49).